# Restricting request types to Blueprint API Action routes

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

I would like to use the Blueprint API's [Action routes](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?blueprint-routes) in production, and the documentation informs me that I can do this as long as I do not unintentionally expose controller logic to `GET` requests.

> `actions` are enabled by default, and can be OK for
>   production -- however, if you'd like to continue to use
>   controller/action autorouting in a production deployment, you must
>   take great care not to inadvertently expose unsafe/unintentional
>   controller logic to GET requests.

Unfortunately, by default, action route responds to all four types of requests - `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`. I would like to deny only certain types of request to a route, while allowing the others to go through. For example, I may wish to accept only `POST` requests to the `bar` action at `/foo/bar`, while denying `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests to that route.

I know that I can use [Policies](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) to restrict controller actions.

```
FooController: {
    bar: false,
},
```

However, it doesn't seem to be as fine grained as I would like it to be. I am only able to either deny all 4 types of requests or allow all 4 types of requests based on the same condition. What I want instead is to always deny 3 out of the 4 types of request, while always allowing the 4th type to go through.

Can this be done without resorting to disabling Blueprint and manually inputting the routes into `/config/routes.js`? If so how?